# What kind of Java / SQL solution do I need for 10 read/write every second in a million line table?

Tags: java, sql, database

If I have an sql table that consist of one million rows. Let's say a user table.

What type of software do I need, in order to handle 10 read/write every second. I was thinking of using a Java NIO server to handle the connections.

But how does the back-end Database work? Could I simply use MySQL on the same computer?

Any insight would be great. Links, reading, examples. books?

I know SQL. I have done alot of SQLite but never created a scalable system to handle this kind of load.

**Edit update,regarding helios comment**

how many reads vs. writes?: 50/50
do you need up-to-date-reads(no delay): YES?
how big is each item?: 10% is 10-15 columns and the rest is 1-3 columns
are you accessing them individually?: NO, non of the USER threads are interacting but there can be simultaneous DB read/write on same row, (just make it synchronized?)

Comment: Well. The load you mention can be managed by a single computer (I think, you should make a test). But if you want it scalable (I mean, capable of supporting a growing number of accesses) you should get a better idea of what is your domain: how many reads vs. writes? do you need up-to-date-reads or the writes can be delayed? how big is each item? are you accessing them individually? can the be apart from other items with no consequences for the logic? With that questions (and others) in mind you can evaluate concrete options. Even "no-sql" databases that are more scalable-friendly :)

Comment: @helios I think i should make it scalable yes. thanks for the info

Comment: Your requirement is small enough that you could create one file per line (the worst thing I could think of ;) and it would still perform ok.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey ,,nice :) . I want to use the best, not the most suitable. Sounds like "no-sql" is the way to go?, considering maybe i get 100 times more then what was expected in traffic

Comment: Using a real database is the way to go. Here is a list 122 no-sql database with a short summary of what they are good for. http://nosql-database.org/

Comment: @peter thanks just what i need. Im only storing a User Class and a User can have many Friends. So far my conclusion is the Document Store MongoDB. Storing a (User)Document with nested Class Friend. If you know, How big Is MongoDb support user group, I see much talk about Mongo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you need 10 transcation/second on  table with million rows.

that is really neither huge data set nor high performance.

MYSQL (currently 5.5+ ,innodb engine) , running on single server,can easily handle that.

you may need read first five chapter of 'High Performance MySQL' published by oreilly.

for nosql-db, i suggest mongodb, see http://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: +1: The performance requirement is not that high, so keeping it simple is the best approach (usually is)

Comment: @Peter Should i use nosql? ..just read the article SQLvsNoSQL... ...http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10770?page=0,2..“Non-SQL gives you a very sharp knife to solve a selected set of issues. If you find SQL too hard to use, you should not try Non-SQL.” What do i have to be afraid of?

Comment: Depending on your lifetime of the project, how much you expect it to grow, your experience, required functionality (do you require relationship queries that SQL offers?) and how much you want to risk by choosing a less popular approach. These things always come with a balance of risk vs benefit. There is the aspect of how much information you find online if you encounter an issue (there are many more MySQL users than MongoDB users for instance). So its purely a balance that you have to strike depending on your context.

Comment: @Erik, There are lots of no-sql servers. simple to tricky. MongoDB is one of the easiest to use.

Comment: @jbx good aspect for consideration. Im so impressed with the performance reading this article. If i use MongoDb i could probable run it on my home Intel i7 computer for a long time before i need to rent Server Computer. And i dont need Relation...http://www.michaelckennedy.net/blog/2010/04/29/MongoDBVsSQLServer2008PerformanceShowdown.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you make use of JDBC Connection Pooling (like C3PO, DBCP etc.) you would be able to have parallel inserts, and you would be able to have 10 threads (or more) simultaneously inserting data. Your limit would then be your platform resources (memory, I/O etc.).

All this would hold however only if the data insertion process itself can be parallel threads (i.e. you do not have a specific requirement to insert records sequentially) and that what you are doing are simple inserts and not something complex that locks the table or causes the other transactions to wait.

Also consider using JDBC prepared statements, and also committing in batches rather than after each record. This would speed up things greatly.

Comment: yes this is my scenario, asynchronous operation. Will read up on the  JDBC